# Question based on calculating the number of days when the work will be completed

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Each of Atul, Yogesh and Riyaz can complete a piece of work in 12 days, 36 days and 54 days respectively. They started the work together, but Atul left after working for 6 days and Yogesh left 8 days before the completion of the work. In how many days was the work completed?

What I did:-

Total work= LCM( 12, 36, 54)= 108 units

Atul work per day= $108/12=9$ units

Yogesh work per day= $108/36=3$ units

Riyaaz work per day= $108/54=2$ units

Total work done by them in 6 days= $(9+3+2)*6=84$ units

Am I doint it wrong? Also, what will be the next step?

Comment: I don't think the Total work = LCM(12,36,54) is correct..

Comment: I have calculated it twice. It came out to be this. @yanko

Comment: I don't understand how you know the total work? it is a variable. I agree that if the total work is 108 then atul , yogesh and RIyaaz's work per day is 9,3,2.

Comment: denote the total work by $T$ then as a function of $T$ you know the amount of work that each of the members do in one day.

Answer (score 0):

First assume, that A do 1 unit of work per day. There are 12 units to do.

Then we can count effectivness of Y and R:
$$A=1,\, Y=\frac{12}{36}=\frac{1}{3},\, R = \frac{12}{54} = \frac{2}{9}$$

Then we can compute their combined effectiveness:
$$[AYR]=A+Y+R = \frac{14}{9},\\
[YR] = Y+R = \frac{5}{9} \\
[AR] = A+R = \frac{11}{9} \\
[AY] = A+Y = \frac{4}{3}$$

Let's denote number of days the work is done as in the question by $X$

Now consider four cases:
a) $X >=14$ 
b) $8\leq X<14$
c) $6\leq X<8$
d) $ X<6$

In a):

- For 6 days they work together ([AYR])
- For X-14 days they work without A ([YR])
- For 8 days there is only R

Our equation is then:
$$6 [AYR] + (X-14) [YR] + 8 R = 12\\
6 \frac{14}{9} + (X-14)\frac{5}{9} + 8 \frac{2}{9} =12 \\
X=\frac{78}{5} = 15.3$$

In b):

- For X-8 days they work together ([AYR])
- For 14-X days they work without Y ([AR])
- For X-6 days there is only R

The equation is then:
$$(X-8) [AYR] + (14-X) [AR] + (X-6) R = 12\\
(X-8) \frac{14}{9} + (14-X) \frac{11}{9} + (X-6) \frac{2}{9} = 12\\
X=\frac{78}{5} =  15.3 >14$$
Thus we've obtained contradiction

In case c):

- For 6 days there are A and R [AR]
- For X-6 days there is only R

The equation:
$$6[AR]+(X-6)R=12\\
6 \frac{14}{9} + (X-6) \frac{2}{9} =12 \\
X=18 > 8$$
Again we've obtained contradiction

In case d) for X days there are A and R [AR]
$$X [AR]=12\\
\frac{11}{9} X = 12\\
X = \frac{108}{11} \approx 9.8 > 6$$
Again we've obtained the contradiction.

So the final answer is, that they've worked for 15.3 days.

Answer (score 0):

Total work= LCM( 12, 36, 54)= 108 units

Atul work per day= 108/12=9108/12=9 units

Yogesh work per day= 108/36=3108/36=3 units

Riyaaz work per day= 108/54=2 units

Atul has worked for 6 days.So Atul has done 6 x 9 =54 units of the work

Let the work completed in x days,then Yogesh has worked for x days and

Riyaas has worked for (x-8) days

Ygesh has done 3x units of the work

Riyaas had done 2(x-8)=2x-16 units of the workSo the work comoleted

Now 54+3x+2x-16=108

Or 5x=70

Or x=14

So the work completed in 14 days

Comment: According to the question, Riyaas has worked for $x$ days and Ygesh for $(x-8)$ days - conversely to your solution.